QGIS Polygon tool adding vertices continuously (unexpected behavior)
I'm having trouble with the polygon drawing tool in QGIS. When I try to create a polygon, instead of adding vertices with single clicks, the tool seems to be continuously adding vertices wherever I move the mouse. This creates an unwanted, squiggly line instead of a defined polygon.

You probably have "Stream Digitizing" activated.

Choose Digitize with Segment to get the behavior you expect or simply press R to switch between mode while digitizing.
